# Does kube-proxy filter HTTP POST payload for JSON content type?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networking

I've encountered rather strange behavior of my kubernetes cluster (1.18.20, calico 3.14.2): when I attempt to upload two-megabyte JSON file to pod via curl through `NodePort` service, transmission is interrupted with `Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.
Traffic capture shows that both client and server receive RST packets from network, but didn't sent them.
Binary file of same size uploads successfully, but JSON is rejected regardless of `Content-Type` specified.
File transfer between pods (using similar commands and same file) proceeds smoothly.
Upload through ingress (also configured using `NodePort`) fails too.
Size of received fragment is always the same, approximately 850K.

I've used `nc -l 80*` instead of real service with the same outcome.

Apparently, `kube-proxy` doesn't like big JSON files.

Is it possible to send big JSON files to pod from external clients, or such a limit is hardcoded?

**UPD1**

Same behavior for fresh cluster (1.22.0, calico 3.20.0).

**UPD2**

System rejects not every big JSON payload, but only several percent of user uploads.
Payload is specially crafted by client application: first part of multy-volume Zip archive is base64-encoded and encapsulated as JSON file ('{ "data": "..." }').
Size of fragment causing connection break is about 640K.

Looks like error in filtering procedure inside of `kube-proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the source of the problem was in misconfiguration of IDS/IPS.

Nothing to do with **kube-proxy**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [conntrack](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html) to solve your connection issue? It simply installs by the following command:

```
apt-get install conntrack #[ debian/ubuntu ]
yum install conntrack #[ centos/redhat ]
```

You can experiment whatever you would like with the max size, but you can start with the following metrics to check if something happens:

```
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets=300
sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=1200
```

Please find more detailed guide [here](https://technology.lastminute.com/chasing-k8s-connection-reset-issue/)

Comment: Yes, I have.

Error reproduces with and without **net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal=1** on idle cluster, **conntrack -E** displays only **SYN_SENT/SYN_RECV/ESTABLISHED** and **CLOSE**.

Problem depends on content of payload, not on it's size.
Communication between pods also isn't affected, but attempt to connect from external computer fails if fragment of file is big enough.

Doubt if it might be linked to conntrack.